# Cache in Yii Memcache full page, partial or key cache

Tags: yii, memcached

I have created this filter

```
return array(
    array(
        'CHttpCacheFilter + View',
        'lastModified'=>Yii::app()->db->createCommand(
             "SELECT MAX(`date_taken`) FROM image")->queryScalar(),
    ),
);
```

It caches all data for `actionView` in php Yii

The issue is I have areas on the page that need to be dynamic.

I have looked at partial cache on that page. This is not bringing performance benefits. The main weight is with the sql query. I tried adding the data to cache key. However data is over 1 mb so this not working too well. Anyone know best way round this

```
/**
 * View for a Image
 * @param string $alias_title the image a user would like to view   
 */        
public function actionView($alias_title)
{
    $associated_image_details =  Image::getImageFromAliasTitle($alias_title);
    $image = Utils::getArrayOrNull($associated_image_details, 0);
    $album = Utils::getArrayOrNull($associated_image_details, 1);
    $tag= Utils::getArrayOrNull($associated_image_details, 2);
    $comment= Utils::getArrayOrNull($associated_image_details, 3);
    $media_set= Utils::getArrayOrNull($associated_image_details, 4);
    $media_gallery= Utils::getArrayOrNull($associated_image_details, 5);
    $media_group= Utils::getArrayOrNull($associated_image_details, 6);

    $this->render('view', array(
        'image' => $image, 
        'album'=>$album,
        'comment'=>$comment,
        'tag'=>$tag,
        'media_set'=>$media_set,
        'media_gallery'=>$media_gallery,
        'media_group'=>$media_group
    ));
}
```

Comment: `The main weight is with the sql query` are you saying the the lastmodified query is the one taking most of the time when using partial caching or are you saying that in the content you need to cache the major part of the time is while performing the sql query?

Comment: am consciencous of page caching as there are dynamic areas on page such as the username of the user logged in. Memcache wont store the data as its over 1mb. The weight of the page is in the initial action for the select of the complete image set. Method above